# @MailSend not working for one user when document is created from another database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Mail comes into a mail-in database.  In that database is an agent that creates a document

```
    Set docIITS = dbIITS.CreateDocument
    With docIITS
        .form = "Informal Inquiry"
        .subject = doc.subject(0)
        '.sendTo = doc.from
        .status="Open"
.. other fields     
        .save False,False
    End With
```

and then calls

```
Call ws.EditDocument(True,docIITS,,,,True)
```

which shows the user the new document created in the other database.  On that form is an action:

```
remark:=@If(instructions="";"Please respond to this as soon as possible.";instructions);

@If(status !="Closed"  & AssignedTo !="";@MailSend(assignedto;"";"";"Informal Inquiry: " + area + " " + Type; remark;"";[IncludeDoclink]);"");
tmpActivity_log:=@If(status !="Closed"  & AssignedTo !="";"**** " + @Name([CN];@UserName) + " sent notification to " + @Name([CN];assignedto) + " at " + @Text(@Now) + @NewLine + activity_log; activity_log);

FIELD activity_log:=tmpActivity_log;

@Command([FileSave]);
@Command([FileCloseWindow])
```

Recently one user has had the problem where the @MailSend() fails.  No errors, just the mail doesn't get sent.  The field activity_log does get updated and the document saved.  If she closes the document and then reopens it from the second database, @MailSend() works as expected.

I created new databases using the designs of these two as templates.  It doesn't matter whether she used the original or the copy of the first (mail-in) database, if the new document is created in the production second database, @MailSend fails.  It doesn't matter whether she used the original or the copy of the first (mail-in) database, if the new document is created in the test copy of the second database, @MailSend succeeds.  The second database has both a default form and a default view.  And this worked for that same user a couple months ago.  Any ideas what might be wrong or how to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is Notes used for other mail, or only for mail from this application? It's an action, so it runs in the user's Notes client.  I'm thinking that there's something wrong with the user's client configuration -- e.g., wrong location document is selected, so mail is going into the local mail.box instead of the server's mail.box. If Notes isn't being used for other email, it would be easy to not notice this.

Comment: It can't be a location document because it sends mail when the document is opened from the second database.  If it were a mail delivery problem, it wouldn't work from anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked the user's mail.box to be sure?

Comment: She has no mail.box.  She's configured so that the mail is on the server.

Comment: Well then, if it's not in a local mail.box and not ending up dead or on hold in the server's mail.box, I have no idea. There is an old notes.ini setting called CLIENT_CLOCK that turns on very low-level logging. I think you have to use it in combination with DEBUG_OUTFILE or DEBUG_CONSOLE, if I remember correctly. If there's nothing in her local log.nsf file to give a clue, then I'd consider turning that on and capturing the output. The debug data is pretty dense, but you never know... It might give a clue. That's assuming it still exists in whatever Notes version she has installed, of course.